# If BuildContext passed to build method refers to parent widget , then what does context passed to build() of root widget refer to?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Here is an example code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main(){
runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    build(context){     //where does this this context point to
        return MaterialApp();
    }
}
```

BuildContext

```
A handle to the location of a widget in the widget tree.
```

Each widget has its own BuildContext, which becomes the parent of the widget returned by the StatelessWidget.build.

Comment: see `BuildContext` properties

Comment: @pskink do u mean from the docs? [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html)  Am not able to get any answer from there.

Comment: so what properties does it have [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html#instance-properties)? did you see `widget` property?

Comment: @pskink yes, it says  "The current configuration of the Element that is this BuildContext." .But since it's the root element there can't be any ancestor element.

Comment: what do you see if you `print()` it? also: did you try to visit all the ancestors using `visitAncestorElements()` method and printing the passed `Element` to the callback?

Comment: printed it from one of my projects where the root was a statefullwidget. It says : MyApp(dirty, state: MyAppState#51bbc) . Does that mean it's pointing to itself?

Comment: @where do I implement visitAncestorElements()?

Comment: @pskink [root](renderObject: RenderView#316b2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE)   This was the output.   Did this:   'context.visitAncestorElements((Element element) { print(element); return true; })'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BuildContext doesn't refer to the parent widget. It refers to the current widget.

So with :

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    build(context){     //where does this this context point to
        return MaterialApp();
    }
}
```

The BuildContext points to `MyApp`.

Comment: [This Article](https://engineering.liefery.com/2019/02/18/flutter-for-newbies-why-you-should-care-about-the-build-context.html) says different.

Comment: It doesn't. The article says the BuildContext is the parent of the widget _returned_ by `build`. So that's the context that is parent of MaterialApp, hence it is MyApp

Comment: In the above article the author wrote :    `  class MyDocumentsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  build(BuildContext context) {
    //context is login screen
 }`       Where login screen was the previous page...

Comment: Then he made a mistake. Just print `context.widget`, and you'll see that it is `MyApp`.

Comment: So the author is wrong i guess since the context will be of MyDocumentsScreen